# Bot calling my php script too fast

Tags: php, web-crawlers

I have a hobby website, where a php script presents a html page displaying information for a particular surname. I am capable of displaying information for over 100,000 surnames. So the script is called like this to generate the http output:

```
/surname.php?surname=Smith
```

The script accesses a database to acquire some of the data for the surname. The script takes some 20ms to execute.

I have an issue where a bot called https://domainsproject.org was calling my script some 50 times a second, triggering 508 errors on some occasions.

So, I'm seeing something like this in my logs:

```
/surname.php?surname=Smith 200
/surname.php?surname=Jones 200
/surname.php?surname=Kelly 200
/surname.php?surname=Walsh 508
/surname.php?surname=Boyle 200
```

If I search for random surnames in search engines, I can find my website for that particular surname. So it is a good thing that my website is being crawled in this manner. However, I would like to slow down the bots. Is this possible? I am hosting my website with a common web hosting company.

Comment: The webserver software may have **rate limiting** options. However, I am assuming you are on a shared hosting plan with no control over the server configuration.

Comment: Yes thats true. For now I have blocked the ip used by https://domainsproject.org.

Comment: My site is also getting hammered by this bot, 1+ years later. I'm also an indie dev and it costs money to set up rate limiting for it.

Anyone else affected by it should consider submitting abuse reports to the hosting company and registrar shown in a whois report.

Answer (score 6):

There are 3 options to my knowledge:

1. If it's a Robots.txt compliant crawler, you can ask it to delay the requests by adding the **Crawl-delay** directive to your robots.txt file:

   ```
   User-agent: Botname
   Disallow: /private/
   Crawl-delay: 10
   ```
2. If your hosting allows and/or you have a content firewall/frontend like Cloudflare or similar, you can configure a **rate-limit** option so that it slows down the request.
3. You can always block the offender, by IP or name so that it doesn't hammer your site at all.

Comment: 4 - submit abuse reports to the hosting company and domain name registrar.

Answer (score 1):

As https://domainsproject.org maintainer I'd like to say that there are limits in
place (random delay - 1-15 seconds, concurrency limited to 2 parallel requests at point of writing this message).

However, having the ability to specify `Crawl-Delay` is actually a good idea.

It is now added to crawler code: https://github.com/tb0hdan/idun/blob/main/robots.go#L63

and will be deployed gradually across crawler nodes.

Regarding IP block - it is better to use that in combination with webserver level checks, i.e. https://github.com/mitchellkrogza/nginx-ultimate-bad-bot-blocker/ (unfortunately for me - Domains Project is there already)

Comment: What other information are you (the "domains project") collecting? From the website, it only appears to collect "domain names"? But then why does this necessitate crawling websites at all, let alone at "50 times a second"?!

Comment: Robots.txt, Favicon, DNS records, SSL info. Considering screenshots.

Answer (score 1):

This crawler crashed a t3.micro server by issuing 240 requests to a Wordpress site in a two-minute window today.  The log records showed it was making 2-8 parallel requests every few seconds.

Rather than implement rate limiting, you can choose to block this bot by adding the following to your robots.txt:

```
# Block Domains Project crawler
User-agent: Domains Project
Disallow: /
```